# Does Webpack install -g, automatically install to nodeJS's package.json? Or is this only for local installs?

Tags: json, node.js, npm, webpack, package.json

Does Webpack install -g, automatically install to nodeJS's package.json? Or is this only for local installs?

So I'm tired of trying to find workarounds for require() is not defined. Meaning I would need a module loader for my project to include modules client side. Well, I've downloaded the famous 'webpack' module loader, globally

```
     npm install -g webpack
```

and I noticed it didn't install to "devDependencies" in my package.json file. But I also install webpack-dev-server, but locally,

```
     npm install webpack-dev-server --save-dev
```

and it was saved into my package.json. Was this saved because I used --save-dev or because I installed locally?

I'm getting an error stating my webpack module I downloaded doesn't have a configuration file, so I'm assuming I install webpack wrong, and maybe it shouldn't have been installed globally. Please help with the understanding of globally and locally, as well as why this -g webpack install didnt get saved to the package.json?

Comment: I never tried to add package.json executing any package install. Instead I run the command npm init in order to create the package.json and start adding packages buy executinh npm install --save-dev or adding manually to the package.json dependencies. After adding manually I execute the command  npm install

Answer (score 0):

The command `npm install --gloabl` will install a package in global scope and make it's bin command available to you globally. This has nothing to do with the folder or project your are in right now. That means a global install will not leave anything in any `package.json` files.

Learn more about npm install: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install

Answer (score 0):

**npm install -g webpack** will save your files in your OS file system.

**npm install webpack-dev-server --save-dev** will save your package in your project directory inside a folder called node_modules.

The later one will make an entry in package.json file so that next time you can install all dependdencies with just **npm install** command. This command installs all your packages listed in package.json.

**Missing Config file:** Its looking for a file called webpack.config.js. More info can be found here: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/